# Include Once inside an Echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, list, echo

I'm trying to echo out a php file which includes only HTML of an Option list as in this example:

```js
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo '<div>
        Select an option:'
        include_once("sortedlist.php")
        '</div>';
}
```

It need's to be echo'ed out because I'm adding the content via AJAX RESPONSE TEXT...

is it possible to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It will be returned to the calling function as a parameter to the success. You can do what you wish with it from there.

Comment: yes possible. So what i want do on above code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<div>Select an option:';
    include_once("sortedlist.php");
    echo '</div>';
}
```

sortedlist.php file has only html code so it will be automatically rendered as html

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<div>Select an option:';
    include_once("sortedlist.php")
    echo '</div>';
}
```